# Should this question remain open?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[SE Challenge: Halachot in which rulings range from permissible to Torah violation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11625/se-challenge-halachot-in-which-rulings-range-from-permissible-to-torah-violatio) is an old question with a bunch of up-votes.  It's a list/survey/riddle question and would probably be closed if it were asked today.

What should we do with this question?  Leave it open (people are still participating)?  Close it and apply a historical lock, so the information remains available but the question is labelled as not a good example to base new questions on?  Something else?

Comment: Nooo! I have another answer!

Comment: @HodofHod, I'm asking the question, not taking pre-emptive action. :-)

Comment: Also, don't forget this question's toladah (derivative): [Halachoth whose rulings range from obligatory to a (Torah) prohibition](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/11634)

Comment: @MonicaCellio I really think we should have a category and/or a tag for list/survey/riddle questions. There is apparently a need for them. I had this problem myself ( http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55627/examples-of-considerations-when-bringing-gifts-to-religious-jews ) and I don't  think I will be the last.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/959/what-is-our-attitude-to-list-questions

Answer (score -1):

My answer: Leave it open and create a "challenge" tag and flag for such questions.

Obviously the site has general standards for most questions. But even we agree that some questions--notably those in the Purim Torah category--do not need to be governed by such standards.

I think a good way of allowing interesting and fun questions to remain on the site without changing the general standards is making a separate category for semi-out-of-the-box questions.

Since there is a risk that these categories could be abused, the privilege of creating such questions might be restricted to those with significant reputation.

In addition to thinking about what is *on* the site, we might also consider the question of what is lost to the site by virtue of not falling completely within its current, very strict parameters. I imagine there is a wealth of Jewish questions, mysteries, enigmas and riddles flowing around cyberspace and people's minds. There may come a day when we want to make room for some of it.

Comment: NB: *All* of the Purim Torah questions are closed. There is a special [temporal exception](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated) whereby they can be posted and answered during ~2 weeks of the year. When that period is over, they're all closed.

Comment: Are you proposing list questions be accepted for a certain period of time only? As you noted we've made exceptions like that before in the case of Purim Torah.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm just saying that whatever grounds allows there to be Purim Torah questions on this site shouldd in theory be extensible further. I don't really see what great difference the limited timeframe makes.

Comment: @DoubleAA That is, in general, I don't think that either "flex" category strictly needs a limited tenure.

Comment: How can you say that without knowing the grounds on which Purim Torah is allowed?